# Why are my balls disappearing?

Tags: javascript, canvas, geometry, physics, collision

Pardon the funny title. I've created a little graphic demo of 200 balls bouncing and colliding, both against the walls and each other. You can see what I have currently here: http://www.exeneva.com/html5/multipleBallsBouncingAndColliding/

The problem is that whenever they collide with each other, they disappear. I'm not sure why. Can someone take a look and help me out?

UPDATE: Apparently the balls array has balls with coordinates of NaN. Below is the code where I push balls to the array. I'm not entirely sure how the coordinates are getting NaN.

```
// Variables
var numBalls = 200;  // number of balls
var maxSize = 15;
var minSize = 5;
var maxSpeed = maxSize + 5;
var balls = new Array();
var tempBall;
var tempX;
var tempY;
var tempSpeed;
var tempAngle;
var tempRadius;
var tempRadians;
var tempVelocityX;
var tempVelocityY;

// Find spots to place each ball so none start on top of each other
for (var i = 0; i < numBalls; i += 1) {
  tempRadius = 5;
  var placeOK = false;
  while (!placeOK) {
    tempX = tempRadius * 3 + (Math.floor(Math.random() * theCanvas.width) - tempRadius * 3);
    tempY = tempRadius * 3 + (Math.floor(Math.random() * theCanvas.height) - tempRadius * 3);
    tempSpeed = 4;
    tempAngle = Math.floor(Math.random() * 360);
    tempRadians = tempAngle * Math.PI/180;
    tempVelocityX = Math.cos(tempRadians) * tempSpeed;
    tempVelocityY = Math.sin(tempRadians) * tempSpeed;

    tempBall = {
      x: tempX, 
      y: tempY, 
      nextX: tempX, 
      nextY: tempY, 
      radius: tempRadius, 
      speed: tempSpeed,
      angle: tempAngle,
      velocityX: tempVelocityX,
      velocityY: tempVelocityY,
      mass: tempRadius
    };
    placeOK = canStartHere(tempBall);
  }
  balls.push(tempBall);
}
```

Answer (score 97, accepted):

Your error comes from this line initially:

```
var direction1 = Math.atan2(ball1.velocitY, ball1.velocityX);
```

You have `ball1.velocitY` (which is `undefined`) instead of `ball1.velocityY`. So `Math.atan2` is giving you `NaN`, and that `NaN` value is propagating through all your calculations.

This is not the source of your error, but there is something else that you might want to change on these four lines:

```
ball1.nextX = (ball1.nextX += ball1.velocityX);
ball1.nextY = (ball1.nextY += ball1.velocityY);
ball2.nextX = (ball2.nextX += ball2.velocityX);
ball2.nextY = (ball2.nextY += ball2.velocityY);
```

You don't need the extra assignments, and can just use the `+=` operator alone:

```
ball1.nextX += ball1.velocityX;
ball1.nextY += ball1.velocityY;
ball2.nextX += ball2.velocityX;
ball2.nextY += ball2.velocityY;
```

Answer (score 21):

There's an error in the `collideBalls` function:

```
var direction1 = Math.atan2(ball1.velocitY, ball1.velocityX);
```

It should be:

```
var direction1 = Math.atan2(ball1.velocityY, ball1.velocityX);
```