# Why aren't my ball (objects) shrinking/disappearing?

Tags: javascript, html

http://jsfiddle.net/goldrunt/jGL84/42/
this is from line 84 in this JS fiddle. There are 3 different effects which can be applied to the balls by uncommenting lines 141-146. The 'bounce' effect works as it should, but the 'asplode' effect does nothing. Should I include the 'shrink' function inside the asplode function?

```
// balls shrink and disappear if they touch
var shrink = function(p) {
    for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        p.radius -= 1;
    }
    function asplode(p) {
        setInterval(shrink(p),100);
        balls.splice(p, 1);
    }
}
```

Comment: `asplode` is not declared in the global scope (or in particular, not defined in a scope accessible to `update`); check our your console.

Comment: Fortunately, that's `balls.splice()` with a `p`.

Comment: you have error `Uncaught ReferenceError: asplode is not defined`. Function `asplode()` is not visible.

Comment: After pulling asplode out of the function block it was in, you get other errors in the console.

Comment: `asplode` isn't in the right scope, `setInterval` should receive a function reference, `splice` needs an index - or maybe the world is just shrinking with you http://jsfiddle.net/5f85b

Comment: Your Counter isn't increasing after 10 anymore!

Comment: @Panique is correct... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11066050/why-are-my-balls-disappearing. You even commented on it then :)

Comment: It's a totally different question. The only thing they have in common is balls. And JavaScript. And attention. Oh and, please, if you want to make jokes, at least be tasteful. (But they're going to get deleted regardless.)

Answer (score 65, accepted):

Your code has a few problems.

First, in your definition:

```
var shrink = function(p) {
    for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        p.radius -= 1;
    }

    function asplode(p) {
         setInterval(shrink(p),100);
        balls.splice(p, 1);
    }
}
```

`asplode` is local to the scope inside `shrink` and therefore not accessible to the code in `update` where you are attempting to call it. JavaScript scope is function-based, so `update` cannot see `asplode` because it is not inside `shrink`. ([In your console](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/8525/how-to-open-the-javascript-console-in-different-browsers), you'll see an error like: `Uncaught ReferenceError: asplode is not defined`.)

You might first try instead moving `asplode` outside of `shrink`:

```
var shrink = function(p) {
    for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        p.radius -= 1;
    }
}

function asplode(p) {
     setInterval(shrink(p),100);
     balls.splice(p, 1);
}
```

However, your code has several more problems that are outside the scope of this question:

- `setInterval` expects a function. `setInterval(shrink(p), 100)` causes `setInterval` to get the *return value* of *immediate-invoked* `shrink(p)`. You probably want

  ```
  setInterval(function() { shrink(p) }, 100)
  ```
- Your code `for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) { p.radius -= 1; }` probably does not do what you think it does. This will immediately run the decrement operation 100 times, and *then* visually show the result. If you want to re-render the ball at each new size, you will need to perform each individual decrement inside a separate timing callback (like a `setInterval` operation).
- `.splice` expects a numeric index, not an object. You can get the numeric index of an object with `indexOf`:

  ```
  balls.splice(balls.indexOf(p), 1);
  ```
- By the time your interval runs for the first time, the `balls.splice` statement has already happened (it happened about 100ms ago, to be exact). I assume that's not what you want. Instead, you should have a decrementing function that gets repeatedly called by `setInterval` and finally performs `balls.splice(p,1)` after `p.radius == 0`.

Answer (score 21):

```
setInterval(shrink(p),100);
```

This doesn't do what you think it does.  This calls `shrink`, passes it `p`, and then passes the result to `setInterval`.  `shrink(p)` returns `undefined`, so this line doesn't actually put anything on an interval.

You probably want:

```
setInterval(function(){
    shrink(p)
}, 100);
```

Comment: @tereško: I can live with that :)